Why would a background layer be missing from a print job that used a flattened PDF? (Book Vault)
I have a client trying to print a book through Book Vault, KDP, and IngramSpark. The artwork includes a white background with a subtle texture. While KDP and Ingram printed just fine, Book Vault keeps printing the book with the background missing—solid white, no texture. According to them, they suspect it's because the PDF wasn't flattened, but even after flattening all art layers and re-exporting, it printed the same way.
This was my process—maybe something I'm doing is causing it:

I created the artwork in Photoshop with layers—300dpi, RGB.
Then I created an InDesign file and placed the PSD file directly into the project with a dynamic link. I added back cover text, publishing information, and barcode.
I embedded all files, including the PSD, and exported it with the PDF/X-1a:2001 preset as a PDF (which also converts it all to CMYK).
The printer printed wrong and asked to flatten the layers.
I went back to my PSD file and merged all layers and resaved it with a new file name.
Dropped that PSD file into InDesign where I had the back copy and barcode, embedded it, and re-exported it.
Printer had no perceivable change. The flat artwork didn't print with a texture in the background.

In both cases, KDP and Ingram printed the entire thing with no issues.
All my design contacts are stumped, the printer is stumped, I'm stumped. The only other time I've had assets just vanish on me in a print job was when a client's own printer didn't have enough memory for the file size—a printer the size of Book Vault shouldn't have that problem. I wonder if somehow the printer isn't seeing the texture in the background when it reads the file, and that's why it just prints white? What's my next step here?
Secondary question—is it generally bad practice to drop a layered PSD file into InDesign and then embed on export? I considered embedding it to do the same as manually flattening the layers, and it saved me a ton of time on my workflow, but if that opens up a bunch of printing risks, I should probably change that regardless of whether it contributed to this issue.

"is it generally bad practice to drop a layered PSD file into InDesign and then embed on export?" -- I do this regularly and often without issues. I think your issue is localized to the print provider. It does not sound as if your file set up is an issue (flattened or not). Especially if other providers showed no problems.

Thanks, @Scott. That was my suspicion too. But despite having done these projects for years now, there's sometimes holes in my knowledge on the back-end of things because I'm self taught. Thanks for the thoughts. I appreciate the help!

Most likely an uncalibrated printer.
Calibration indicates the printer how color values are supposed to be.
I would assume any modern digital printer would recognize a non-pure white shape and add some ink to it.
But the truth is that you can not do anything about it, but to, either choose another provider or to adapt your design to it.
To do this, send a chart of colors as reference, print it, and have it on your desktop, near your keyboard but away from that cup of coffee.

This was my process—maybe something I'm doing is causing it.

The Design process starts with being aware of the characteristics and limitations on the print system you are using. That is why you use a test chart made by your specific provider when possible (digital print), or a standardized chart (sheeted offset, spot inks)


Is it generally bad practice to drop a layered PSD file into InDesign and then embed it on export?

I do not understand how you are using "embed" here.
When exporting (PDF) the raster images are always embedded. The real point here is the version of the PDF profile.
A print profile, X1, X3, X4, flattens the features that the specification does not allow. It could be transparency, on the oldest profiles for example.
IMHo a good practice is to use an old standard that actually does what you need to do.
CMYK? CMYK+Spotink? Grayscale?
But, depending on my workload or the precision I need on a project I make a copy and manually flatten it.
I do not want "software" to figure out what I meant by blending, overprinting, TAC, etc. Yes, probably they would do a really good job. However I have not done extensive tests to rely on an automated process.
The more variables you let loose (layers, blending modes, color modes), the fewer arguments you have when something goes south.

Thanks for your extensive answer. For embedding—in InDesign, I can see my linked items in a window, including my placed PSD file. I can right-click and hit "embedd link" and then the asset isn't disconnected if the PSD file is changed or moved. I figured that was a faster way to protect against lost layers than manually flattening (I only manually flattened things if the automatic CMYK conversion looked really bad). But I suppose you're saying it doesn't matter, because the PDF profile embeds it anyway on export. And thanks for the secondary answer about the benefits of manually flattening.

@JayDee in 35+ years I've never "flattened" an InDesign file or intentionally embedded any images in InDesign. I just export to PDFx... and that should be enough.
